# How to fetch facebook login domain existed within NodeJS Server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I try call facebook login in NodeJS Server using React fetch but it dosen't work

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authroization');
    next();
  });

  ...

  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback",
    profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'gender', 'link', 'locale', 'name', 'timezone', 'updated_time', 'verified', 'displayName']
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    var user = profile;
    // NOTE: ‘my_token’ we will use later 
    var payload = {
      _id : "facebook:" + user.id, 
    };

    var secretOrPrivateKey = JWT_SECRET;
    var options = {expiresIn: 60*60*24};

    jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, options, function(err, token){
      user.my_token = token;
      done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

router.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate( 
    'facebook', 
  )
);

router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate(
    'facebook',
    {
      session: false,
      failureRedirect: '/' 
    }
  ), (req, res) => {
    res.json({
      token: req.user.my_token
    })
  }
);
```

It is properly work.

But fetch('https://localhost/auth/facebook) at React doesn't work with show this error. How to fetch facebook login domain existed within NodeJS Server

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: Have you tried just writing `fetch('/auth/facebook)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you access https://localhost/auth/facebook? Via browser?
Seems like the Origin Header in the Request is missing.
If you are using browser, check the request headers.
If you access via command line (wget or curl) add the Origin header.

Comment: I add <a href='https://localhost/auth/facebook'></a> in JSX. Then it's work! Thank you